# How to change a borders background with a colorpicker

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

i have a xaml resource file with some definitions of `DataRemplate`s. In one `DataRemplate` I have a border background bound to a property of its `DataObject`.

I also have a `ColorPicker` user control which is part of the `ContextMenu` of the border.

Now I'm trying to bind the dependency property "CustomColor" of the `ColorPicker` to the color/background property of the border. How to do this?

Do i have to bind to the "Background" property of the border or to the "Color" property of my dataobject?

```
<Border x:Name="projectRect"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Background="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"
        BorderBrush="#737377"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="4"
        IsHitTestVisible="True">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProjectId}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="4" />
    <Border.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="colorPopup"
                     StaysOpen="True"
                     Style="{StaticResource ColorPickerContextMenuStyle}">
            <Border Background="GhostWhite">
                <local:CustomColorPicker x:Name="cp"
                                         CustomColor="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource colorConv}}"
                                         diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
            </Border>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Border.ContextMenu>
</Border>
```

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Both properties should be bound to the Color in your data-object, to make sure the Border is updated if the `ColorPicker` changes the property the dataobject needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

How you do the bindings depends on your context. In most cases dataobjects are found in the `DataContext` of your respective object but with ItemsControls and the like that may not be the case. For general help with bindings see the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).